# Different implementations for Autocomplete-light

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-autocomplete-light

I was able to implement the autocomplete-light function using a class based view format:

```
class UserAccountsUpdate(UpdateView):
    context_object_name = 'variable_used_in `add_user_accounts.html`'
    form_class = AddUserAccountsForm
    template_name = 'add_user_accounts.html'

    def add_user_institution_details(request):
    ###code###
```

With this form:

```
class AddUserAccountsForm(autocomplete_light.ModelForm):
    required_css_class = 'required'
    name = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=autocomplete_light.TextWidget('InstitutionAutocomplete'), 
        label="",)
class Meta:
    model = Institution
    autocomplete_fields = ('name')
    fields = ('name',)
```

With urls.py:

```
url(r'^profile/add_user_accounts/', UserAccountsUpdate.as_view(), name='add_user_accounts'),
```

However, I am trying to debug my code in the class based view (i.e. add_user_institution_details).  I have decided to change from the code about by call the method directly.

So updated the view to this:

```
def add_user_institution_details(request):
    context_object_name = 'variable_used_in `add_user_accounts.html`'
    form_class = AddUserAccountsForm
    template_name = 'add_user_accounts.html'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddUserAccountsForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
        ### code ###
```

and updated urls.py to:

```
url(r'^add_details', add_user_institution_details),
```

For some reason in the second implementation, the autocomplete search box has disappears completely.  What am I missing?

Comment: Is it intended that the function-based view `add_user_institution_details` only accepts POST requests?

Comment: @Leistungsabfall Yes. The intended behaviour is that the user will select an institution. Then I can grab the id of that institution from the DB and save it to the user table associated with that user. The problem here is also that the autocomplete bar isn't even rendering. Not sure why it works in class for but not function form.

Comment: I think your misunderstanding how function-based views work. Assuming the URL `add_details` should be rendering the autocomplete **and** accept `POST` requests, you actually have to return your form as context variable in order to show it for `GET` requests (like this: `return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form})`).